# implement MuPdf in IOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, mupdf

I want to implement MuPdf in my application.

I have added all library files including fitz and pdf , but i can't build my code as there are showing these errors :

Apple Mach-O Linker Error
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_fz_bound_annot", referenced from:

I have downloaded & run MuPdf master code and its working. But when i try to implement code in my application its not work.

I have added all necessary Framework.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you set `Imported Type UTIs` in plist file?

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest that the .h files have to be referenced. So you might be missing hopefully an #import "header".

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you have done wrong. It is possible it is one of these things:

1. You intended to copy over the .a files that the normal mupdf project build but didn't
2. You did copy over the libraries, but you used ones that are not 'fat' libraries nor build for i386
3. You didn't copy in the Run Script phase used in the sample project with calls `bash build_libs.sh` to build the libraries.

However I have just created a [CocoaPod for MuPDF](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MuPDF), and created an [example application based on that pod](https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example). If you are happy with CocoaPods this is likely to be the easiest way to import MuPDF into your project.